# Drag n Drop on Input File

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have a form with an input to add a file to upload. I need to create a drop area where user can drag and drop a file and press the button to upload. I have written the following code so far:

HTML Code

```
<form name="form_name" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="submit" name="button_1"  id="button_1" role="button"/>
  <input type="file" value="" name="file_upload" id="file_upload_id">
    <div class="dropzone2" id="dropzone2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <img src="https://www.mylink.com/img.jpg">
    </div>
</form>
```

I need to change the JS code bellow to automatically select the dropped file like the user had chosen the file through the explorer window. Any tips on how to do it?

JS code

```
        function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
```